# Problem with a service jboss using remoting objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Does anybody know which mean this error `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection`, this throws when i'm to pass a java.sql.Connection to my service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database connections are not serializable, i.e. they cannot be transferred from one VM to another.

I can't really help you more than that, since you've given no context about your problem.